# Como hacer aparecer un texto cuando se cumple condicion JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando con js y tengo una duda a la hora de imprimir texto en el DOM con js.

Tengo un boton que suma `+ 1`  a `var click` y quiero que cuando el número de click llegue a 5, aparezca el texto de la funcion `sumar()`

```js
var click = 1;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = click;

function sumar() {
  click = click + 1;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = click;
}
if (click > 5) {
  function sumar() {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Es más que 5";
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 id="demo"></h3>
<h3 id="demo2"></h3>
<button id="button" onclick="sumar()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que en tu js no estaba llamando a la función masque().
Prueba esto:

```js
var click = 1;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = click;

function sumar() {
  click = click + 1;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = click;
  if (click > 5) {
    masque();
  }
}

function masque() {
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Es más que 5";
}
```

```html
<h3 id="demo"></h3>
<h3 id="demo2"></h3>
<button id="button" onclick="sumar()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Agradeceria mucho si alguien me ayudara a hacer un ejemplo ejecutable con este código. Estoy probando pero la verdad no logro hacer q se pueda ejecutar.

Comment: En el editor hay un boton que dice *fragmento JavaScript/HTML/CSS* con el puedes agregar un ejemplo ejecutable JS. Tambien puedes usar el atajo del teclado `CTRL + M`